# Determine function parameter types and parameter count at runtime

Tags: c

Say I got a simple program that can load a DLL from user input, and then parse input parameters, so that we can pass them to some DLL function, and call it.

The problem here is, in C I can't determine amount of arguments, and their types at runtime,
so assume we have recieved the string `dlcall sin 3.14` so we call function sin with argument 3.14, our parser knows what type is that and can say its a double. So do `dlsym` to get the function pointer and call it, right? Well there's the problem, how do we cast function to the types and most importantly count given without switching through every return type?

here's some pseudocode

```
lib = dlopen(parse('dlopen lib.a')->libname)
res = parse('dlcall sin 3.14')
dlsym(lib, res->function_name)
// How do we cast it, not knowing parameter count at the compile time, and their types?
?? (*fnptr)(??)

// How do we called, not knowing parameter count at compile time?
fnptr(??)
```

Comment: You're going to end up doing something "fun" like [C/Invoke](https://www.nongnu.org/cinvoke/) or [libffi](https://sourceware.org/libffi/).

Comment: Also, in general, you can't get the signature of a function from a dynamic library (unless you also have the header), so you'll have to infer it from the user's call, which will be really "fun".

Comment: Or I suppose you could go the [ctypes.sh](https://github.com/taviso/ctypes.sh) route, and make the user tell you the signature explicitly in their call.

Comment: A lookup table of function signatures is one possible option.  It's a bit limited however.

Comment: The reality is, you only need to know the size of each of the parameters, but that can vary depending the architecture the DLL is compiled for.

Comment: You can use debug symbols for this in theory. Take a look into DWARF direction. If there is no debug symbols.. and no headers... it's impossible to do. For C++ it's possible up to some point, excluding return type though.